# Telnet Server process not loading user profile on first access c# console app

Tags: c#, windows, telnet

I hope somebody can help.

I'm experiencing an issue on windows when a telnet service is accessed for the first time and the user has never accessed the box, that c# application is then failing to prepare the config due to the appdata roaming folder location being empty. The next time the session is created and the profile has been setup, the application works as expected.

**Exceptions:**

> Configuration system failed to initialize
>
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()    at
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
> sectionName)    at
> System.Xml.XmlConfiguration.XsltConfigSection.get_s_ProhibitDefaultUrlResolver()
> at
> System.Xml.XmlConfiguration.XsltConfigSection.CreateDefaultResolver()
> at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Load(XmlReader stylesheet)
>
> Absolute path information is required.
>
> at
> System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[]
> str, Boolean needFullPath)    at
> System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess
> access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean
> checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)    at
> System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess
> access, String path)    at
> System.Environment.InternalGetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder,
> SpecialFolderOption option, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)    at
> System.Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder)

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you for your time.